# word highlighting library without jquery

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJs project. I don't have jQuery in my project. I need a library for mentioning people and adding tags for articles. every Angular library I've found for that uses jQuery. Is there any library without jQuery?

Comment: @Editors and reviewers: See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is no.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I this case, there are many question like this, but not in Angular. they've asked for plain JavaScript plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a library based on otobox.js from Afshin Mehrabani, [angulat-otobox](https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/angular-otobox), have a look. it's easy to use.